# shell_exec with PHP

Tags: php, shell-exec

I am attempting to run [apktool](http://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/) (just a tool to unpackage android applications) over the web using PHP shell_exec but it isn't working.  Does anyone know why this might be?

This is what the line of code actually looks like:

```
   $output = `apktool d -f $file_name`;
```

Any suggestions would help I'm totally at a loss why I run the php and nothing happens.
Thanks!

Comment: Probably important to call http://php.net/escapeshellarg

Comment: Are any errors output?  Try using the `exec` function instead, this will give you access to the output of the `apktool` command if you use the second or third arguments.  Post the output back here if you want more help.

Comment: apktool is usually run using a simple shell command `apktool d -f $file_name` which is why I basically just copied that command and put it in the backticks.  I also tried it with `shell_exec` and `exec` and nothing so far.

Comment: And I know php.ini has `safe_mode` off and it is not in `disable_functions`  I feel like I'm doing it right which is why I'm so confused.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution.
Create build.sh file with exec permissions and write there this code:

```
#!/bin/bash
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin/:/usr/sbin/:/bin:/sbin/:/bin/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin

/usr/local/bin/apktool b -d $1 $2
```

--
usage ./build.sh

```
<? php shell_exec("/path/to/build.sh $dir $file"); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

check if you web server (probably apache) has sufficient permissions to execute apktool. Include the whole path to the apktool binary. Use single quotes if there are spaces in your file name.

Check your web server's logs if there is any detail why the command is not executed.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your actual line is:

```
 $output = shell_exec(`apktool d -f $file_name`);
```

And that your php.ini file does not have `safe_mode` turned on or have `shell_exec` listed in
the `disable_functions` directive.